# Получение идентификатора по объекту в lsfusion

Tags: объекты, lsfusion

Есть класс документов, у каждого объекта этого класса есть уникальный идентификатор:

```
CLASS Document;
id(Document d) = DATA INTEGER (Document);
```

Как можно по id получить сам документ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью оператора `GROUP`:

```
document(id) = GROUP MAX Document d BY id(d);
```

aльтернативный вариант:

```
document(id) = GROUP AGGR Document d BY id(d);
```

Во втором случае будет создано [ограничение](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Constraints/) на уникальность идентификатора документа. В результате при попытке создать два документа с одинаковым идентификатором будет выдано сообщение об ошибке.